# Blog tutorial docs isAuthorized missing return false?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // All registered users can add articles
    if ($this->request->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of an article can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete'])) {
        $articleId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Articles->isOwnedBy($articleId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Need I return false if the isOwnedBy() test fail? like this:

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // All registered users can add articles
    if ($this->request->action === 'add') {
        return true;
    }

    // The owner of an article can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete'])) {
        $articleId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->Articles->isOwnedBy($articleId, $user['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

I found this code at:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what

Comment: Are you asking if this tutorial has a bug in it? What does your modification do? If it works more correctly with your modification then your modification is likely correct - but perhaps you have changed the behaviour of the app from the intention of the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, the parent `isAuthorized()` method will return `false` for all non-admins

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

So in that specific case, no, you don't have to, to be exact, you *must* not, as this would cause only owners being able to edit anything at all, since the admin role would not get checked anymore.

ps. this type of question is probably better suited on IRC or the Google group.

Comment: sure.. do you think I have to close the question?